# Need help identifying this grapevine and how to care for it

Tags: identification, plant-health, plant-care, plant-recommendations

Hi I live in South New Jersey and there's an old grapevine from the previous home owners I would like to get it to fruit as the past couple years it hasn't been successfully fruitful.
Please see below pix....need help with pix I keep getting error when uploading a pic :(

Comment: Without seeing a picture, I can say grapes need heavy pruning to be productive , especially if ignored a few years. t

Comment: May be or ornamental grape vine - no fruit.